# Is this a valid approach to determine group types of small orders?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

> Is the following a valid approach to determine group types of small orders?

Let $G=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ be a set. Suppose that $\Theta=\{\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n\}$ and $\Gamma=\{\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_n\}$ are subgroups of $S_n$ such that:

> 1. $\theta_i(j)=\gamma_j(i), \forall i,j=1,\dots,n$;
> 2. $\theta_i\gamma_j=\gamma_j\theta_i, \forall i,j=1,\dots,n$.

Then the composition law:

$$a_ia_j:=a_{\theta_i(j)}=a_{\gamma_j(i)}$$

gives $G$ a group structure. In fact:

- *closure*: by definition;
- *associativity*: by 1 and 2 above, $$\begin{align}
  (a_ia_j)a_k&=a_{\theta_i(j)}a_k\\
  &=a_{\gamma_k(\theta_i(j))}\\
  &=a_{(\gamma_k\theta_i)(j)}\\
  &=a_{(\theta_i\gamma_k)(j)}\\
  &=a_{\theta_i(\gamma_k(j))}\\
  &=a_ia_{\gamma_k(j)}\\
  &=a_i(a_ja_k).
  \end{align}$$
- *unit*: since $\Theta$ and $\Gamma$ are groups, $\exists \bar i, \bar j$ such that $\theta_{\bar i}=\gamma_{\bar j}=\iota$; then, $$a_{\bar i}a_j=a_{\theta_{\bar i}(j)}=a_{\iota(j)}=a_j, \forall j$$
  and $a_{\bar i}$ is left unit; likewise, $a_{\bar j}$ is right unit; now, $a_{\bar j}=a_{\bar i}a_{\bar j}$, because $a_{\bar i}$ is left unit; but also $a_{\bar i}a_{\bar j}=a_{\bar i}$, because $a_{\bar j}$ is right unit; then, $a_{\bar j}=a_{\bar i}$;
- *inverse*: $\forall j, \exists k$ such that $\theta_j(k)=\bar i$; then, $a_ja_k=a_{\theta_j(k)}=a_{\bar i}$, and $a_k$ is right inverse of $a_j$; likewise, $\forall j, \exists m$ such that $\gamma_j(m)=\bar i$; then, $a_ma_j=a_{\gamma_j(m)}=a_{\bar i}$, and $a_m$ is left inverse of $a_j$; but $$\begin{align}a_k&=a_{\bar i}a_k\\
  &=(a_ma_j)a_k\\
  &=a_m(a_ja_k)\\
  &=a_ma_{\bar i}\\
  &=a_m.
  \end{align}$$

As a first use of this formulation, I notice that, for any $n$-cycle $\sigma$ and $\bar k \in \{1,\dots,n\}$, the (abelian) option

$$\theta_{\sigma^i(\bar k)}(\sigma^j(\bar k))=\gamma_{\sigma^i(\bar k)}(\sigma^j(\bar k)):=\sigma^{i+j}(\bar k), i,j=1,\dots,n \tag 1$$

is a valid one, *i.e. fulfills the conditions 1 and 2*, for every $n$, and gives rise to the cyclic group type. In fact, from $a_{\sigma^i(\bar k)}a_{\sigma^j(\bar k)}=a_{\sigma^{i+j}(\bar k)}$, we get $a_{\sigma^m(\bar k)}=a_{\sigma(\bar k)}^m$ (induction on $m$) and then $G=\langle a_{\sigma(\bar k)} \rangle$. Then, cyclic groups exist of every order: this is trivial, but here my focus is to look at ciclicity just as an entry test for the "allowed structures" approach (1 and 2).

I'm wondering whether we can pursue this way (to explicit $\Theta$ and $\Gamma$ fulfilling 1 and 2) to show that:

a) if $n$ is prime, then $(1)$ is the *only* valid option (for some suitable choice of $\sigma$ and $\bar k$);

b) if $n=4$, then the *only other* option is the one establishing Klein's Group;

c) if $n=6$, then the *only other* option is the one establishing $S_3$.

`REMARK`. I'm aware that finding the number of groups of a given order $n$ (up to isomorphism) has purely group-theoretic answers (based on Cauchy and Sylow theorems), but I'd like to retrieve the known results a), b) and c) from "structure constraints" 1 and 2.

---

**Edit (Aug 20)**

Note that, by conditions 1 and 2:

$$\begin{align}
(\theta_i\theta_j)(k)&=\theta_i(\theta_j(k))\\
&=\theta_i(\gamma_k(j))\\
&=(\theta_i\gamma_k)(j)\\
&=(\gamma_k\theta_i)(j)\\
&=\gamma_k(\theta_i(j))\\
&=\theta_{\theta_i(j)}(k)
\end{align}$$

so that: $$\theta_i\theta_j=\theta_{\theta_i(j)}$$

Likewise,

$$\begin{align}
(\gamma_i\gamma_j)(k)&=\gamma_i(\gamma_j(k))\\
&=\gamma_i(\theta_k(j))\\
&=(\gamma_i\theta_k)(j)\\
&=(\theta_k\gamma_i)(j)\\
&=\theta_k(\gamma_i(j))\\
&=\gamma_{\gamma_i(j)}(k)
\end{align}$$

so that: $$\gamma_i\gamma_j=\gamma_{\gamma_i(j)}$$

Therefore, if we define $\varphi(\theta_i):=\gamma_i$, we get:

$$\begin{align}
\varphi(\theta_i\theta_j)&=\varphi(\theta_{\theta_i(j)})\\
&=\gamma_{\theta_i(j)}\\
&=\gamma_{\gamma_j(i)}\\
&=\gamma_j\gamma_i\\
&=\varphi(\theta_j)\varphi(\theta_i)
\end{align}$$

and finally

$$\Theta \cong \Gamma^{\operatorname{op}}$$

Comment: Your primary question (in the title) should be included in your post.

Comment: All groups certainly exist in this way ($\Theta$ is the left action of $G$ on itself by multiplication, $\Gamma$ the right), but it's not obvious why this construction should be useful. What suprises me is that a corollary of this fact implies $\Theta$ and $\Gamma$ are isomorphic, which I don't think is obvious from the two conditions. As an aside, $\Theta=\Gamma=\langle (1,2,4,3,5)\rangle$  is one option for $n=5$ which is not exactly the same as (1).

Comment: @Robert Chamberlain - I miss why your aside would be an exception to $(1)$: by calling $\sigma=(1,2,4,3,5)$, isn't $\langle \sigma \rangle=\{\iota,\sigma,\sigma^2,\sigma^3,\sigma^4\}$ following the rule $\sigma^i\sigma^j=\sigma^{i+j \mod 5}, \forall i,j=0,1,2,3,4$?

Comment: You are correct, but that's not exactly what (1) says. Assume $\Theta=\langle\sigma\rangle$ satisfies (1) and consider $\theta_1$. $\theta_1(1)=1+1=2$ so $\theta_1=\sigma$, but $\theta_1(2)=1+2=3\ne\sigma(2)$ . When you say only valid option, I assume you mean to "up to isomorphism" or up to some other equivalence?

Comment: It seems to me that $\Theta=\Gamma=\langle \sigma \rangle$ does not fulfill 1 (I mean the bullet point), because e.g. $\sigma^3(2)=5\ne 1=\sigma^2(3)$, so it can't be an option for $n=5$.

Comment: You would not have $\theta_i=\sigma^i$, you could choose $\theta_1=\gamma_1=1$ then define inductively $\theta_{\sigma(i)}=\gamma_{\sigma(i)}=\sigma\theta_i$, so $\theta_2=\lambda_2=\sigma$, $\theta_4=\lambda_4=\sigma^2$ and so on. Then  $\theta_{\sigma^i(1)}(\sigma^j(1))=\sigma^{i+j}(1)=\gamma_{\sigma^j(1)}(\sigma^i(1))$

Comment: I see. So, I think that $(1)$ can be generalized to take into account your aside, and then leave the claim a) still potentially true.

Comment: Edited to address the comment about the isomorphism between $\Theta$ and $\Gamma$ ($\Gamma^{op}$, actually).